# How to forecast future data based off 5 year average?

Tags: python, pandas, time-series, forecasting

I have 5 years of historical data at a daily granularity;

```
             Volume
2010-01-01   21
2010-01-02   38
2010-01-03   34
.
.
.
2015-12-31  48
```

There is a lot of seasonality in the data so I'm simply looking to do a forecast for the next 12 months using a 5 year average.

I can do this by;

```
df_fut = df.groupby(by=[df.index.month, df.index.day]).mean()
```

Is there anyway to plot this so that the forecast is part of the current dataset?

Comment: Are you looking for `df['Volume'].mean()`?

Comment: Yes, in one sense. But looking for a mean on a daily granularity.. so the average  of every March 1st for each of the 5 years of data if that makes sense?

Comment: df_fut = df.groupby(by=[df.index.month, df.index.day]).mean()

This works to find the average but then it is tricky to try and make this a dynamic forecast.

Comment: This works for getting the mean of March 1sts: `df[(df['a'].dt.month == 3) & (df['a'].dt.day == 1)].mean()`. Does it answer your question?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you have a column called `date` (of type `datetime64`) and a column called value (of type `int` or `float`):

```py
avg_march_1sts = df[(df['date'].dt.month == 3) & (df['date'].dt.day == 1)]['Volume'].mean()
#                                  ^^^^^^^^^^ March             ^^^^^^^^ 1st
```

Comment: Haha I have accepted it! It does answer what I asked but I think I probably need to think about how to phrase the question properly as it doesn't exactly tell me how to use the averages as a forecast (my fault, not yours!) :)

Comment: i did already :)